# Cannot invoke nextint() on the primitive type int

Tags: java

So I'm learning Java and maybe he didn't explain well enough how scanners work and their limits or maybe I'm looking over something silly...  but I'm getting an error on `answer = answer.nextInt();` I don't get this error for `bomb` but it's used pretty much the same way...

Code:

```
    Scanner yesNo = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    // 
    //answer auto set to no. goes to first if, then asks for confirmation,
    // then check answer again and go to if, else if or else. 
    //
    int answer = 0;
    while (answer != 1)
        if (answer == 0) {
            System.out.println("In how many seconds should we detonate?");
            int bomb = input.nextInt();
            //this number will be used later in else if (answer == 1)
            System.out.println("Is " + bomb + " seconds correct? 1 for yes, 0 for no");
            answer = answer.nextInt();
            //error above "Cannot invoke nextint() on the primitive type int"
            //Need this to grab a number from user to assign a new value to answer
```

What do? Thanks.

Comment: Um.  `answer = input.nextInt()`?

Comment: imput is being used to hold bomb though, doesn't that matter? I still need the input from bomb

Comment: No, why would that make a difference?  `input` is a `Scanner` which lets you get more and more input.

Comment: you can't call functions on a primitive, it doesn't exist.

Comment: They didn't explain that.  Maybe I just need to find a better tutorial. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you want to get the next *random* int. To do that you must create a [random generator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) with `n = new Random()` and then get the next random integer with `m = n.nextInt()`.

Comment: "input is being used to hold bomb though" - no. `input` only holds the next position in your typed line. Suppose you typed in `100 200`. After `input.nextInt()`, input does not remember `100`, and it has no idea about `bomb`. `bomb` remembers `100`. `input` remembers that the next time someone calls `nextInt()`, it should start scanning from position 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

int is a primitive value. It is not an Object and it has no methods.

probably you want to do

```
answer = input.nextInt();
```

Comment: I see what I did.  Must have been crosseyed that day and renamed my scanner in one area and didn't change the other.  'yesNo' should have been 'answer'.  derp.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, you have one Scanner instance with paramether System.in, so it will "record" your keyboard (I assume that yesNo scanner is not used). Then, you have a int variable called "answer" which you assign zero value. Finally you have another variable called "bomb" where you will get your requested value.

As I see in your answers' comments, you're wrong in one thing: "input.nextInt()" is an int value. When you use input.nextInt(), you're sending it a message that says "Hey bro, give me the first int that this stupid human have pressed", but you aren't doing anything more. "input" is only a scanner (as it class name says) that records keystrokes.

So in fact, when you do "input.nextInt()" you'll get an int value, and when you do "bomb = input.nextInt()" or "answer = input.nextInt()" the only thing that you're doing is giving "bomb" or "answer" that int value.

Answer (score 2):

nextInt() is a function that is part of the object type Scanner.  In order to call .nextInt() you must have an object of type Scanner.

So the line "int bomb = input.nextInt();" works fine, since "input" is an object of class Scanner.  That function runs and it returns another object, an integer, from input, which is stored in int bomb.

The line "answer = answer.nextInt();" fails to compile because "answer" is an object of class integer.  integer does NOT have a function called nextInt().

The appropriate line is "answer = input.nextInt();" using your Scanner object to return another integer to store in "answer".

Answer (score 0):

```
int answer = 0;

answer = answer.nextInt();
```

You are calling `nextInt()` on an int. You need to call it on the scanner:

```
answer = input.nextInt();
```